# Weird behaviour in text patterns after migration JasperReports Server on Linux

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

I'm in the process of moving an old *JasperReports Server (3.5.0)* from a Windows environment to a Linux one. So far everything went well. I can generate reports from my application, schedules .etc

But I have noticed this weird issue where in few of the reports, the text formatting pattern that is applied for some fields are not displaying correctly.

Here's the portion of the .jrxml where the pattern is applied

```xml
<textField pattern="###0" isBlankWhenNull="false">
    <reportElement uuid="ea9933c9-1863-474f-a6e2-65cfe3f07426" x="390" y="9" width="144" height="20" forecolor="#000000"/>
    <textElement>
        <font fontName="Verdana" isBold="true" isUnderline="false"/>
    </textElement>
    <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.Number"><![CDATA[$V{TotalEM} + $V{TotalEC} + $V{TotalED}]]</textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

In the Windows environment this is working fine and the text is displaying correctly i.e `279` but when it's comes Linux it is showing only `27`

In the process of migration apart from the build I haven't change anything. I'm using the same DB as well, where's all the reports are stored and other configurations + settings.

Comment: I wouldn't say you have the "Verdana" font by default on Linux environment. You may try installing it from some package...

Comment: Try to change the font , just select all the text fields and change the font to SansSerif or any other font.